# agregar fila en tabla con boton

Tags: javascript, html, table

Tengo mi tabla html:

```js
function agregarFila()
{

    document.getElementById("cantidad").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>';
}

function eliminarFila() {
    var table = document.getElementById("cantidad");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    //console.log(rowCount);

    if (rowCount <= 1)
        alert('No se puede eliminar el encabezado');
    else
        table.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
```

```html
 <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <table id="cantidad" class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="width:100px;">#</th>
                                                <th style="width:100px;">XXX</th>
                                                <th style="width:100px;">XXXa</th>
                                                <th style="width:100px;">XXX</th>
                                                <th style="width:100px;">XXX</th>
                                                <th style="width:100px;">Acciones</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" onclick="agregarFila()">Agregar Fila</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarFila()">Eliminar Fila</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

y estoy haciendo referencia a mi archivo de js antes del `body` de esta manera:

```
  <script src="~/Js/xxxx.js"></script>
```

Pero me sigue diciendo que el `onclick` no esta definido, como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: A la función `eliminarFila()` le falta la llave de cierre.

Answer (score 2):

Oye no se si te has dado cuenta de que te falta una llave al final del segundo metodo copie y pegue tu codigo en CODEPEN y me marco el error por la llave del metodo que falta

te dejo el link a codepen para que puedas verlo

https://codepen.io/ChristianAO/pen/abJewyw

Comment: Ya lo resolvi solo cambie en mi script el ~ por .. y ya me funciona

Comment: que estas utilizando para ejecutar el codigo quizas asi pueda ver el error que te marca